# access local host from virtual machine

Tags: web-application, metasploit, kali-linux

I'm trying to penetration test a site i created which is currently hosted on my machine using AMPPS and i am also running Kali Linux in Virtual box but how to get the VM to talk to the site in the local host on my machine? I am new to pen testing so all help is appreciated. thank you

Comment: That depends on your setup. Usually there is some sort of network bridge between the host and the VM, using the 192.168 subnet for example. But this depends on how you setup your VM.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a networking question:

First, you'll need to verify that you have a network adapter (virtual) on each OS and that they are on the same subnet.  You can run `ipconfig /all` on your windows host (I'm assuming your base OS is Windows) and `ifconfig` from the Linux terminal to verify this configuration.

You'll also need to ensure that AMPPS is set to use your virtual NIC that is on the same subnet as you Linux VM.

Once you've verified this, you can then proceed with your testing by sending them to the IP address on the Windows box from you Kali VM.